# How do I fix this 2D controller code so that my game object goes at 100% speed instantly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, 2d

Basically I made my object in unity move around with virtual joystick, but I can't make it move at 100% instantly, it is smoothed and top speed is reached only when handle reaches the outline of the joystick. How do I remove the smoothing?

I tried couple of things I learned from tutorials like the following code but since I am a beginner and can't think of much stuff that could help.

```
public float runSpeed = 5f;
public Joystick joystick;
Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;



// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float horizontal = joystick.Horizontal;
    float vertical = joystick.Vertical;

    Vector2 move = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
    Vector2 position = rigidbody2d.position;

    if (joystick.Horizontal || joystick.Vertical >= .2f)
    {
        position = position + move * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if (joystick.Horizontal || joystick.Vertical <= -.2f)
    {
        position = position + move * -runSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        position = position + move * 0f * Time.deltaTime;
    }


    rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);
```

Error   CS0019  Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'bool'  Assembly-CSharp

Comment: both arguments of the `OR` need to be or equate to `boolean`. its not like you would normally say it `this OR that is less than`, it needs to be `this is less than OR that is less than`

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if (joystick.Horizontal || joystick.Vertical >= .2f)
{
    ...
}
```

To:

```
if (joystick.Horizontal >= value || joystick.Vertical >= value)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fixes the error in the code but it doesn't work as I expected it to, still thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not exactly unity savy , put do you have a line of code like this : gameObject.addforce(something);

Comment: I don't... I've read in some tutorials that I need to add velocity to my object, but I am a pleb to do that, I can copy the code and make it work with keyboard, but dunno how to implement that on virtual joystick

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to remove inertia when you change direction. Make velocity as zero when you change direction. It feels you move fast.

But in real world, movement is following newton's first law. so every time you have been trying to change direction. It is affected from the last velocity because newton's first law. so movement will be changed slowly.

Comment: rigidbody2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;